# Can we change the live question update slightly?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, live-refresh, new-questions

If you click the `x questions with new activity` button, then x number of posts get added, which is great, but, x number of posts at the bottom of the page don't get removed, so if you keep clicking the `x questions with new activity` button you'll end up with a massively long page (as I've just found out on SO).

For example,

<sub>The quality's poor, because I've had to zoom out as far as Chrome would let me, in order to fit it all in.</sub>

[image: Screenshot]

Don't you think it would be a good idea to remove these older posts?

Comment: You can just refresh the page. They don't bother me otherwise, and I tend to get longer pages than that =P

Comment: @Jerry Yeah I know, still it would be nice if the older posts could get removed. I have as well, that was just an example (there's 52 posts in that shot, I think), I've seen around 200ish once.

Comment: Presumably if you're clicking the button to show new questions, you've already finished with the ones on your screen, no? I don't really see how this is a problem.

Comment: @Laura Not necessarily, I may want to click the button just see what's new. IMHO, It just seems like an unfinished system, new posts get added, but the old ones never get removed.